# Mesmo formulário de download para páginas diferentes, como salvar em qual página foi feito o download?

Tags: php

O site de um cliente possui o mesmo formulário para todas as páginas (onde há a possibilidade de download de arquivo, a pessoa deve preencher antes de efetuar algum download). Só que o cliente quer saber em qual página o cliente estava quando efetuou o download.
Minha dúvida é o que eu poderia fazer para salvar no banco de dados além dos dados do formulário, a url aonde a pessoa estava, algo do tipo.

Segue código da função de cadastro abaixo:

form_text; ?>
            cover) && $report->cover): ?>
                cover->file_name); ?>" alt="Capa do title) ? $report->title : "Relatório"; ?>">

```
    <div class="register-section__column">
        <?php echo form_open(site_url("subscriptions/register"), array("class"=> "register-section__form")); ?>
            <div class="register-section__input-container">
                <label for="name" class="register-section__label"> <?php echo lang('form-name'); ?> </label>
                <input name="name" type="text" class="input" placeholder=" <?php echo lang('place-name'); ?> " required>
            </div>
            <div class="register-section__input-container">
                <label for="email" class="register-section__label"> <?php echo lang('form-email'); ?> </label>
                <input name="email" type="text" class="input" placeholder=" <?php echo lang('place-email'); ?> " required>
            </div>
            <div class="register-section__input-container">
                <label for="phone" class="register-section__label"> <?php echo lang('form-phone'); ?> </label>
                <input name="phone" type="text" class="input" placeholder=" <?php echo lang('place-phone'); ?> " required data-mask-type="phone">
            </div>
            <div class="register-section__input-container">
                <label for="organization" class="register-section__label"> <?php echo lang('form-company'); ?> </label>
                <input name="organization" type="text" class="input" placeholder=" <?php echo lang('place-company'); ?> " required>
            </div>
            <div class="register-section__input-container">
                <label for="purpose" class="register-section__label"> <?php echo lang('form-destiny'); ?> </label>
                <div class="select-mask">
                    <select name="purpose" class="select" required>
                        <option value=""> <?php echo lang('form-destiny-bf'); ?> </option>
                        <option value="negocios"> <?php echo lang('form-destiny-business'); ?> </option>
                        <option value="pessoal"> <?php echo lang('form-destino-personal'); ?> </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="register-section__input-container">
                <label for="associated" class="register-section__label"> <?php echo lang('form-associated'); ?> </label>
                <div class="register-section__input-radio-group">
                    <div class="container-radio">
                        <input id="associated_yes" type="radio" name="associated" value="1" required>
                        <label for="associated_yes"> <?php echo lang('form-associated-yes'); ?> </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container-radio">
                        <input id="associated_no" type="radio" name="associated" value="0" required> 
                        <label for="associated_no"> <?php echo lang('form-associated-no'); ?> </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="register-section__input-container">
                <button type="hidden" class="submit"> <?php echo lang('form-register'); ?> </button>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pegue o nome da página com basename( **FILE** ), depois é só salvar no DB.

```php
$pagina = basename( __FILE__ );
```

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.basename.php

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar um `input` do tipo `hidden` dentro do seu formulário que possua o valor da `URL` atual da pagina, veja:

```
<input type="hidden" name="origin" value="<?= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
```

Dessa forma sempre que o formulario for enviado ele incluirá também o nome da pagina da qual ele foi submetido.

```
$data = $this->input->post();
// $data tera um valor "origin" com a url da pagina da qual o formulario foi enviado
```

Outra opção também é pegar a "url anterior" a qual o formulário esta sendo processado:

```
$previousURL = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Comment: Boa atarde, seria isso?

<button type="hidden" value="<?= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" class="report-type__header__button js-scroll-to-download">Download</button>

E como eu faria no controller? Pra salvar a url no banco